# Initializing a list with over two items

Tags: android, list, app-inventor

Is it possible to initialize a list with over two items in [App Inventor 2](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/)? By default the "make a list" block only takes two inputs and I can't find the way to add a third one:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on

[image]

then drag and drop "item" from left to right:

[image]

This adds a third input:

[image]

Comment: what is app inventor 2 by the way if you can share ?